# How to print a page using javascript for every php while loop?

Tags: php, javascript

I want to print a page using javascript in php while loop. Please help me by giving an advice.

eg:

```
$q=mysql_query("SELECT name, address FROM member_table);
while ($r=mysql-fetch_row($q)){
echo $r['0']."<br />".$r['1'];
echo 'javascript:window.print()';
}
```

But this is not working. Please help me.

I want to print the page similiar to Print But this should be automatic as while condition will bring more result in looping process

Is there any way to send the page directly to printer one by one from loop or other method. Please help me by giving an example

Comment: Why are you using JavaScript when you can print it directly with PHP? Or are you refering to AJAX?

Comment: Do you mean print to the screen, or print to the printer? Also, if this code is copied directly, you're missing a " after your SQL statement.

Comment: So you want to print row one on to a sheet of paper, rows one and two on a second sheet, rows one, two and three on a third … and so on?! That sounds insane.

Comment: _"But this is not working"_ - why not? Errors? Unexpected behavior? Please explain step by step what you want to achieve, what you expect and what really happens.

Comment: You can't mix your PHP and JavaScript this way.  PHP is server-side, JavaScript is client-side.  Furthermore, you don't really have control over the print process.  All you can do is launch the print dialog, and sometimes even that won't work.  You're better off outputting your whole document, and then print.

Comment: I think more info is needed for you to get a solution that is helpful. Also, if you are going to print the code from php as you suggested, you at the very least need to echo your javascript code enclosed with <script></script> or it will just print the code right on the page for all to see...

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide more details on what you're trying to do. PHP is server side while javascript is client side. When php is done producing the page (loops or not) you still have just 1 page rendered. I am not sure what javascript:window.print() in the loop gives you.

If you want to trigger the page to print after the whole thing is rendered, you can put

```
<script>
javascript:window.print(); 
</script>
```

at the bottom of your page but not in your loop.

Comment: If I add this at bottom of the page, then how the loop will work. Means what will be the mean of loop. Is there any way to send the page directly to printer one by one from loop or other method. Please help me by giving an example

Comment: That's exactly my question. What are you trying to do? PHP is server side script that runs first. Then javascript (client side) when it gets to your browser. You can't have a piece of js code run inside your loop on the server and send to printer. What's gonna happen is what @quentin mentioned - insanity, although in a slightly different way. You will have X number if window.print() statements written out to your page by php and then executed one after another when you get to the browser. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You are right. I never thought about this. is there any option. Please help me how to do it

Comment: @IndianGirl I'm not sure I'm understanding your question, but are you trying to use JavaScript to call the browser's print function and want to do so one page at a time?

Comment: @IndianGirl 

If so, the method you are trying in the OP is not going to work. You need to use AJAX (jquery is easy enough, I would recommend looking into it) to make calls to the PHP script and have it return one page at a time (pass it some get or post vars to keep track of which page/row you're on). Then call print and after that you can run another AJAX call to the PHP script for the next page, and so on. I'm not sure how you'll handle the time between prints as you will need to account for the user taking time to confirm or reject the print dialog...

Comment: @AlexeyGerasimov I think you're answer is the best solution to having php call javascript's print given the way the OP has posted. However I think If I'm understanding her correctly, she is going to need to use ajax to be able to print one page at a time in this way. Or possibly add a settimer after that print statement to change set the window location to the same php script just with the next iteration of the loop, maybe?

Answer (score -2):

Don't use echo for javascript output.

```
<?php while { ?>
    Javascript here
<?php } ?>
```